# ElasticSearch: Avg aggregation for datetime format

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-py

I am stuck regarding an elastic search query using python

I have data such as:

```
{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "gdUJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "user_name": "prathameshsalap@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-21 09:00:01",
}

{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "gtUJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "user_name": "vaishusawant143@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-21 09:15:01",
}

{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "g9UJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "user_name": "prathameshsalap@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-22 07:50:00",
}

{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "g8UJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "user_name": "vaishusawant143@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-22 04:15:01",
}
```

Here, for each user give working hours for different date(21 and 22). I want to take an average of each user's working hours.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query" : {"match_all": {}},
     "aggs": {
      "users": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "user_name"
          },
          "aggs": {
              "avg_hours": {
                  "avg": {
                      "field": "working_hours"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

This query not working. How to find the average working hours for each user for all dates? And, I also want to run this query using python-elastic search.

**Updated**
When I use ingest pipeline as @Val mention. I am getting an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "processor_type" : "script",
        "script_stack" : [
          "\n        def workDate = /\\s+/.split(ctx.working_h ...",
          "                        ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "\n        def workDate = /\\s+/.split(ctx.working_hours);\n        def workHours = /:/.split(workDate[1]);\n        ctx.working_minutes = (Integer.parseInt(workHours[0]) * 60) + Integer.parseInt(workHours[1]);\n        ",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 24,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 49
        }
      }
.....
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The problem is that your `working_hours` field is a point in time and does not denote a duration. For this use case, it's best to store the working day and working hours in two separate fields and store the working hours in minutes.

Comment: How to do that? @Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `working_hours` field is a point in time and does not denote a duration.

For this use case, it's best to store the working day and working hours in two separate fields and store the working hours in minutes.

So instead of having documents like this:

```
{
    "user_name": "prathameshsalap@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-21 09:00:01",
}
```

Create documents like this:

```
{
    "user_name": "prathameshsalap@gmail.com",
    "working_day": "2019-10-21",
    "working_hours": "09:00:01",
    "working_minutes": 540
}
```

Then you can use your query on the `working_minutes` field:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query" : {"match_all": {}},
     "aggs": {
      "users": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "user_name.keyword",
              "order": {
                 "avg_hours": "desc"
              }
          },
          "aggs": {
              "avg_hours": {
                  "avg": {
                      "field": "working_minutes"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

If it is not convenient to compute the `working_minutes` field in your client code, you can achieve the same thing using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html). Let's define the pipeline first:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/working-hours
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "dissect": {
        "field": "working_hours",
        "pattern": "%{?date} %{tmp_hours}:%{tmp_minutes}:%{?seconds}"
      }
    },
    {
      "convert": {
        "field": "tmp_hours",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    },
    {
      "convert": {
        "field": "tmp_minutes",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ctx.working_minutes = (ctx.tmp_hours * 60) + ctx.tmp_minutes;
        """
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": [
          "tmp_hours",
          "tmp_minutes"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to update your Python client code to use the new pipeline that will create the `working_hours` field for you:

```
helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='user_log', doc_type='logs', pipeline='working-hours')
```

Comment: So, How to extract date and hours? And, how to convert hours to min using elastic query?

Comment: Since you want an average of working hours, what date do you want? Converting hours to minutes is easy, you can do it in your client code: `working_minutes = hour * 60 + minutes`

Comment: I don't want any particular date. I want to work hours of each user for all dates. Like here for the user 'a' working on 21(7h:30min) and 22(3h:00min) dates. so for the user, 'a' avg working hours is  5h:15min. I hope you got it what I want. Thank you.

Comment: So you just need the average working hours of each employee and that's what the above query gives you. If you ever need a date range constraint you can add it to the query part.

Comment: yeah, the above query is fine. but the only problem is extracting time filed from working hours and convert into min using elastic search. There is any function for extracting time and convert into min in elastic DSL query?

Comment: How do you index your data?

Comment: I have a CSV file. using bulk 
with open(path) as files:
    reader = csv.DictReader(files)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='user_log', doc_type='logs')

Comment: It's given error for the pipeline.  
def workDate = /\\s+/.split(ctx.working_h ...",
          "              ^---- HERE"

Comment: Are you sure that all your documents have a non-null `working_hours` field?

Comment: when I run the ingest pipeline it's given error. and my working_hours not having a null value.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error please?

Comment: Let's do it differently without regular expressions. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. It's working. how to use ingest pipeline with python elasticsearch?

Comment: When I run the query it's given error: "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [user_name] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."

Comment: You should use the `user_name.keyword` field instead of `user_name` in the terms aggregation.

Comment: If I want to sort user_name with respect to avg working hours. where do I add the sort function in the query? @Val

Comment: One more question I want to know how to use multiple filed not match_all{}. Like I have an id, user_name, working_hours, phone_no, Address, working_minutes. I only want user_name and working_minutes. Thanks for your help. @Val

Comment: I think it's best if you create a new question, this one is solved.

Comment: I have created a new question-related with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349069/elasticsearch-select-multiple-fields-in-query-not-match-all @val