# Elasticsearch: Save aggregations query into CSV file

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have data such as:

```
{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "gdUJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "user_id": 105,
    "user_name": "prathameshsalap@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-21 09:00:01",
    "date": "2019-10-21",
    "working_minutes": 540   
}

{
  "_index": "user_log",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "gtUJpXIBAoADuwvHTK29",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "user_id": 106,
    "user_name": "vaishusawant143@gmail.com",
    "working_hours": "2019-10-21 09:15:01",
    "date": "2019-10-21",
    "working_minutes": 555
}
```

Here I have multiple fields like user_id, user_name, working_hours, date, working_minutes. I only want to choose user_id, user_name, and avg_hours (after calculating avg_working_minutes for each user).

```
body = {
    "query" : {"match_all": {}},
     "aggs": {
      "users": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "user_name.keyword",
              "order": {
                 "avg_hours": "desc"
              }
          },
          "aggs": {
              "avg_hours": {
                  "avg": {
                      "field": "working_minutes"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

es_obj = Elasticsearch()
response = els_obj.search(index='user_log', body)
# save into csv
with open(path, 'w') as files:
    header_present = False
    for doc in response['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
           w = csv.DictWriter(files, my_dict.keys())
           w.writeheader()
           header_present = True
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

It's return output like:

```
user_id  |  date    |         user_name       |  working_hours,   | working_minutes
---------|----------|-------------------------|-------------------|----------
  105    |2019-10-21|prathameshsalap@gmail.com|2019-10-21 09:00:01|   540
  106    |2019-10-21|vaishusawant143@gmail.com|2019-10-21 09:15:01|   555
```

Here It returns all user_id, user_name, working_hours, date, working_minutes. I don't want all of those fields. So, how to select multiple fields(user_id, user_name, and avg_hours) in this query?

expected output:

```
user_id  |         user_name       | Avg_hour
---------|-------------------------|----------
  105    |prathameshsalap@gmail.com|   450.55
  106    |vaishusawant143@gmail.com|   350
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all fields"? All you get in the response is the user name and the average working minutes

Comment: When I print or store the response it's given me all user_id, user_name, working_hours, date, working_minutes. I only want to user_id, user_name, and avg_working_hours. @Val

Comment: Well, maybe show the response you get and what you expect instead

Comment: I am sorry. It's my fault. When i run query it's workinf properly in kibana console but when I want save query response in csv file it's not given as I want. @Val